# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{8^x-8}{x-1}$ without using L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate without using L'Hopital rule
> $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{8^x-8}{x-1}$$

Help me with this limit.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Since $f'(a)$ is defined as $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, for such limits you don't need that rule.

Comment: You should show also your work and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $t = x - 1$,

$$ \lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{{8^x - 8}}{{x - 1}} $$

with $x = t + 1$.

Substitute $t$ into the expression:

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{{8^{t + 1} - 8}}{{t}}$$

and we have
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{{8(8^t - 1)}}{{t}} $$

Remember that

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a^t-1}{{t}}=\log a. $$

$\therefore, \ \lim\cdots =8\log 8$.

Comment: There are 2 negative votes? What Have I wrong? Someone explain me!!!!!

Comment: probably because it's a low quality question, I did not downvote though

Comment: @SineoftheTime I agree partially with this reason. But I have seen the vote positive. One vote of closure. Hence I have given an answer.

Comment: già. Queste sono le regole purtroppo :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the Taylor series of the function $f(x) = 8^{x}$ at $x = 1$.

Comment: Taylor series and L'Hopital rule are actually about the same idea when we have "good" functions :)